Problem Printing the Bibliography on Overleaf
I'm a beginner in Overleaf and I have an Overleaf project, in which I have defined the citation using (\cite{}) command, to choose from a citation file imported from Mendeley called "library.bib", and it works and I get to choose from the list of the citations, however, when I check the reference list I only find the file name printed, but no reference list, and of course there is no hyperlink between the citation and the reference list at all, meaning that clicking on the citation in the text does not transfer me to the reference page.
I don't know if the problem is because the ".bib" file contains "@misc" files, so it's not a standard biblatex and does not provide the standard format for the citation file. (photo attached)


and this is the code I have got in the main.tex file:

and this is the code in the settings.tex file:

and these are the available "usepackages":

I hope you can help with my problem as I have a deadline for submission and I'm really confused with all this coding.

When asking questions, avoid posting screenshots of text or code. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into your question. While many people are willing to help, screenshots make it difficult for them to assist you effectively. Additionally, diagnosing and solving problems requires more than just a description; not everyone is familiar enough with LaTeX to identify issues from a description alone. Please edit your question to replace screenshots with text and specify the errors Overleaf is reporting.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  I would recommend copying everything over to a new project and removing everything that you think is unrelated to getting citations to appear.  You should be able to get it down to 30 lines of code.  And I'm not seeing any \cite commands in what you've shown us.

The problem is I got this project copied from a friend to do my thesis on, and each time I remove something the file closes the pdf view, and I really don't know what to remove and what is not important and what is.

The overleaf is not giving errors in this field, and I don't know where is the problem. is it a wrong citation from the bib file, or it's something I'm doing

Welcome! (1) I got this project copied from a friend to do my thesis on. Don't. (2) Images of code are useless. They can't be copy-paste-compiled for testing. They are hostile to people who depend on screen-reading software and they cannot be searched or indexed. Whatever code and/or errors you want to show us should be copied into your question as text. (3) You've shown no code which should result in a reference list. (4) Your preamble is a mess. You are loading incompatible packages. This includes conflicting packages for managing your bibliography. Comment every package in your ...

... preamble and your settings file unless you know what it is for and that you are using it. Uncomment any which prove necessary. Working with a preamble like this is like trying to swim for shore with three suitcases after a shipwreck. The enterprise is doomed and the sooner you abandon them, the better your chances of reaching land.

The usepackages load natbib and the settings.tex load biblatex. Those two packages are completely incompatible and this alone will cause errors that may be so severe that no bibliography or citation is produced. You need to get rid of one of the two. But this alone will probably not fix things. It appears that the \addbibresource command is used in the document body. This is wrong: It needs to be used in the preamble after biblatex is loaded. That's all I can say from a cursory glance at the screenshots.

You need to provide an example you can not expect people to debug an image. But that list of packages is rather unreasonable you should start by removing any that are not used. Also if your overleaf project has errors (a red error count at the too of the view) don't even look at the pdf output, look at the error messages and if they are not clear, copy th emessages here and ask about them.

just the fact that you load so many packages twice, graphicx, enumitem,ragged2e, ... indicates the package list has not been considered at all and is just a random collection

I'm so sorry to cause any confusion, of course, kindly find here below the code from the settings.tex and main.tex.

%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\usepackage[margin=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,polyglossia,titling,graphicx,verbatim,synttree,enumerate,multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\makenomenclature
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
%gb4e
\definecolor{main}{HTML}{5989cf}    % setting main color to be used
\definecolor{sub}{HTML}{cde4ff}     % setting sub color to be used
\definecolor{corn}{rgb}{0.98, 0.93, 0.36}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{teagreen}{rgb}{0.82, 0.94, 0.75}

\tcbset{
sharp corners,
colback = white,
before skip = 0.2cm,    % add extra space before the box
after skip = 0.2cm      % add extra space after the box
}                           % setting global options for tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox{boxH}{
colback = sub,
colframe = main,
boxrule = 0pt,
leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight
}
\newtcolorbox{boxN}{
colback = corn,
colframe = main,
boxrule = 0pt,
leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight
}

\newtcolorbox{boxF}{
colback = sub,
enhanced,
boxrule = 1.5pt,
colframe = white, % making the base for dash line
borderline = {1.5pt}{0pt}{main, dashed} % add "dashed" for dashed line
}
\newtcolorbox{boxS}{
colback = lightblue,
colframe = main,
boxrule = 0pt,
leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight
}
\newtcolorbox{boxQ}{
colback = teagreen,
colframe = main,
boxrule = 0pt,
leftrule = 6pt % left rule weight
}

%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,backgroundcolor=yellow!80]{todonotes}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{norsk}
% choose and scale font as desired, taking into account possible reduction during printing
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.05]{Noto Sans} % or another font
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.06} % stretch distance between baselines
\frenchspacing
\newcommand{\University}{University of Stavnager, Norway}
\newcommand{\Thesisdesc}{Master's Thesis}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% first page of chapter
\fancyhf{} % comment to keep the normal header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % comment to keep rule
\fancyfoot{} % comment to put page number at bottom
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small \thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{} % no footer
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

considering that now I have modified the bib file to be exactly in the same format of LaTex standard, and it is printing the reference list .... HOWEVER, it is printing it in alphabetic and I want to modify it to numeric but when I do I lose the pdf view and the number of errors surges to the roof

Thank you for posting the code as text and not as an image. Unfortunately, code is extremely hard to read in the comment. You can, however, edit your question to include your code there. Make sure to mark it up as code, so it is easier to read (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/35864). Do note though that the code we could see so far contains far too many packages and other stuff to be useful. I really recommend you start from a much smaller preamble. That way you'll run into far less trouble. ...

... As it stands now, we will have a really hard time suggesting improvements and answering your questions, since we cannot run your code (it references files we don't have etc.). You may want to have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 to see how you can post code that is useful for us and that we can run. It really helps if you test that your code is useful if you try to compile it in a new, empty Overleaf project first.
